# von Neumann Universe as a model of ZFC

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory

I've seen people say things like "We will work in the von Neumann Universe (VNU) as our model of ZFC.” But can't you do all of mathematics syntatically, as in, come up with formal proofs in some proof system (e.g. natural deduction), since first-order logic is both sound and complete? And also, even if some formula is modeled by ZFC inside the VNU, it is not guaranteed for the same formula to hold in *all* models that model ZFC, so how is this first approach even legitimate?

Comment: What does "getting your hands dirty" mean?

Comment: Not sure what I meant by that either. Edited.

Comment: Do you accept axiom of regularity as part of ZFC ?

Comment: Yes I do, along with extensionality, pairing, power set, union, infinity, schema of restricted comprehension, schema of replacement, and choice.

Comment: Can you give a specific example of where you've seen someone say something like that?

Comment: Ok now I can’t actually find anything… maybe I misremembered.

Comment: You’ve “seen” not heard ‘people say things like "We will work in the von Neumann Universe (VNU) as our model of ZFC.”’  So presumably youve seen it in print. Citation needed — who says “VNU”??

Comment: I have never seen or heard anybody say anything like what you are asking about. So I second @BrianO: please provide a specific reference. MSE works far better if we have specific questions to consider.

Comment: There is “NFU”, a system of set theory, but the analogy is illusory. That’s an acronym for “New Foundations with Urelements”, Jensen’s mod of Quine’s system NF.

Comment: I am voting to close this question because we need actual references to comment on. "I've seen ..." is not enough.

Answer (score 2):

The completeness theorem tells you that $ZFC \vdash \varphi$ if and only if $M \vDash \varphi$ for all models $M$ of ZFC.
Hence, to prove a formula, just pick any model $M$ of ZFC. Since you accept regularity as part of ZFC, that means that $M$ is actually equal to the Von-Neumann Universe built inside $M$. That's why you can assume working in the VNU.